# rsync - exlude specific files from directories that are included

Tags: linux, rsync

I have this script:

```
#!bin/bash
AMB="specific_dir*/***"
SRC="/path/to/dir/"
DST_1="user@host1:~/path/to/dest/"
DST_2="virkantas@host2:~/path/to/dest/"
DST_3="nodbaltic@host3:~/path/to/dest/"
for DEST in $DST_1 $DST_2 $DST_3; do
    rsync -av --include=$AMB --exclude='*' $SRC $DEST
done
```

It Synchronize directories that have there name start with 'specific_dir' and everything what is inside excluding all other directories that are in `SRC` directory. That is good, but what I also want to exclude are `.pyc` files that are inside those `specific_dir` directories.

How could I specify what to exclude from directories that where included (or just how to exclude `.pyc` files, but keeping the rule to exclude every other directory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
rsync -av --exclude='specific_dir*/***.pyc' --include='specific_dir*/***' --exclude='*' $SRC $DEST
```

**NB**: order of filter rules (eg: include, exclude) is important.